# No Longer Showing Paid Traffic

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

About a month ago, we had a Wordpress site that went down due to a billing issue with hosting. They had to restore via backup. Since then there has been no Paid Traffic showing in our Analytics, although UA is tracking. We get most of our traffic via Adwords. I have tried everything I can think of and still can't get it to work! Some details:

- We use Tag Manager (there were no edits in there prior to this event)
- The only edit to the site was made when we switched from Tag Manager to straight UA script (post event), which didn't work either so we switched it back
- Yes, the Analytics and Adwords accounts are linked properly
- We tried adding UTM strings to the destination URLs
- We tried turning off auto-tagging in Adwords
- We tried turning off auto-tagging and then adding UTM
- We tried setting up a brand new Analytics account
- Finally, we moved the site onto a different host

NOTHING has worked. I have checked everything I can check. Is it a code issue?? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here's the site: [www.advancedwaterrestoration.com](http://www.advancedwaterrestoration.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Tag Assistant - https://get.google.com/tagassistant/  You can use this tool to watch your tags and see if they fire properly, and what data they send.